# MySQL query to select items in a linked table based on AND

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count, distinct

I have a table **tblPhotos** of photo details:

```
| photoID | photoName |
| ------- | --------- |
| 1       | w         |
| 2       | x         |
| 3       | y         |
| 4       | z         |
```

and another table **tblPhotoTags** of tags to photos:

```
| photoID | tagID |
| ------- | ----- |
| 1       | 1     |
| 1       | 2     |
| 2       | 1     |
| 3       | 2     |
| 4       | 1     |
| 4       | 2     |
```

I am trying make a couple of queries that will pick out the photos that have any given tags, either AND or OR. In the example let's say I am searching for the photos linked to tagID 1 AND/OR 2.

**OR** should pick out all of the photos (1, 2, 3 and 4).

**AND** should only pick out 1 and 4.

I have the following for **OR** which works fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblPhotos.photoID FROM tblPhotos 
    INNER JOIN tblPhotoTags ON tblPhotos.photoID = tblPhotoTags.photoID 
    WHERE tblPhotoTags.tagID = 1 OR tblPhotoTags.tagID = 2
```

But I am struggling to work out how to do the AND query.

Comment: A `tagID` can only have one value, so `tagID =1 AND tagID =2` will have no results. Either link a second time to the `tblPhotoTags`, or use aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the ids of the photos, then there is no need to join to `tblPhotos`.

For the 1st case (`OR`), use `DISTINCT` and just a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT photoID
FROM tblPhotoTags
WHERE tagID IN (1, 2);
```

For the 2nd case (`AND`) use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT photoID
FROM tblPhotoTags
WHERE tagID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY photoID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- the number of tagIDs in the IN list
```

If you also want the name of the photos then join to `tblPhotos`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM tblPhotos p INNER JOIN tblPhotoTags t
ON t.photoID = p.photoID
WHERE t.tagID IN (1, 2);
```

and:

```
SELECT p.photoID, p.photoName
FROM tblPhotos p INNER JOIN tblPhotoTags t
ON t.photoID = p.photoID
WHERE t.tagID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY p.photoID, p.photoName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- the number of tagIDs in the IN list
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3dca1387ca7ba59dc27b2c67e1ef6a6).

Comment: Tremendously helpful. For simplifying the question I shortened the requirements a little so I still need the inner join but then IN and COUNT do the job perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yes - all working perfectly. Thanks again.